# Textbox readonly attribute issue with my struts application

Tags: javascript, html, struts

In my struts 1.2 application i have some fileds in text box which is in readOnly= "true" always. I will populate all the values with out any problem, but the problem is when i click on the text box the cursor is blinking on it when i try to hit backspace button it goes to my previous page end up with session expired error on the previous action.

also some scenario I am populating the text box value and i am making that text box to readOnly = "false" allowed user to end some value here when they press backspace to remove the values which is there already it goes to previous page.

Please help to avoid this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `disabled` rather than `readonly`. Disabled elements cannot be focused, so no confusing blinking cursors.

```
<textarea disabled="disabled">content</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks primatology for ur reply.Yes I tried with disabled also but for the textbox I am populating the values from DB dynamically. so when i do that its not able to bind the data so it end with exception.

Comment: @sudha, Disabling the text field shouldn't at all affect populating the data. What server-side framework are you using? (And can you post the relevant bits of code?)

Comment: But the problem with this disabled is when you try to get the data from the bean object in textbox or textarea like above it will be null.

Comment: @sudha, there's a sneaky fix for that. Leave your textarea disabled, then create a hidden input field with the data you want. (Note that this is not secure; any user with Firebug can still modify the input.) 

`<input type="hidden" name="real-name" value="real-value" />`